# Problems with UNLOAD and the DELIMITER Informix

Tags: informix, unload

I am using UNLOAD in Informix with the DELIMITER "|" but I have problems because in some fields it has as part of the data the value | and then it gives me more fields than the correct ones, I tried with other separators but it's the same.
Is there a better way to export the data than UNLOAD or is there a way to export each field enclosed in double quotes and delimited by "|"?

I am using the following:

```
UNLOAD TO "/ruta/al/archivo/nombre_tabla.txt' DELIMITER '|'
SELECT * FROM nombre_tabla;
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having - in unloading the data or using the unload file to load it back, perhaps into another database? 
Using Informix 12.10.FC15 this works as expected in that a | character in a char column is prefixed with a backslash as "\|" in the unload file.

Comment: It sounds as if the problem is in the software you are using to post-process the unloaded data, rather than in the unloaded data itself.  Have you tried using a control character (control-A or control-G, for example) as the value in the `DBDELIMITER` environment variable (or in the `DELIMITER "^G"` clause in the UNLOAD statement)?  Unless your data contains that character too, you should be OK with that.

Comment: I'm using Informix 12.10.FC14.

It is not possible to use the delimiter "^G", in fact it only allows to use a single character, when using it it gives the error:
Invalid delimiter. Do not use '\\', hex digits or multi-byte characters.

Comment: I found another more optimal way to export, it would be, as I understand it, as a dbexport. This generates the file in informix format, that is, as the data is saved in the informix tables, the problem now is that I don't know how to import this type of file and encoding in PostgreSQL.
Will there be a way?


`SELECT * FROM nombre_tabla
    INTO EXTERNAL agt_ext
    USING (FORMAT 'INFORMIX',
            DATAFILES ("DISK:/ruta/al/archivo/nombre_tabla.unl"));}`

Comment: The control-G (marked as `^G`) is a single character.

Comment: I have scripts for converting Informix UNLOAD format to CSV format.  If PostgreSQL can import those, then you may be in luck.  Contact me by email — see my profile.  (The scripts are in Perl, and the `unl2csv` script uses the `Text::CSV` module.)

Comment: The unload files produced by `dbexport` are in the some format the UNLOAD statement in DB-Access produces.  The big advantage of DB-Export is that it unloads the whole database with a single command, rather than requiring to unload each table separately.